# non-conformable arrays : How do I add multiple matrices with varying row lengths together?

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have 17 matrices with varying row lengths, however, they all have the same 6 column names. Each element in the matrix is a count of transitions. I would like to add all my matrices together to get the total count of each transition.

There are 36 possible row names so I've made a matrix with row names of all the possible combinations and it has elements of zero and the 6 column names.

The idea is to add the zero element matrix to all the 17 matrices so that they all have the same rownames. The next step would be to add all the updated 17 matrices together.

But when I try to add the matrices together I get this error:

```
Error in all.crossings + count.mat000102 : non-conformable arrays
```

My zero element matrix only differs from the other 17 matrices by the number of row names:

```
          k
ij        Aa A Baa Ba B Caa
 A-A      0  0   0  0 0   0
 A-Aa     0  0   0  0 0   0
 A-B      0  0   0  0 0   0
 A-Ba     0  0   0  0 0   0
 A-Baa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 A-Caa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-A     0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-Aa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-B     0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-Ba    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-Baa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Aa-Caa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-A      0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-Aa     0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-B      0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-Ba     0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-Baa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 B-Caa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-A     0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-Aa    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-B     0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-Ba    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-Baa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Ba-Caa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-A    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-Aa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-B    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-Ba   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-Baa  0  0   0  0 0   0
 Baa-Caa  0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-A    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-Aa   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-B    0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-Ba   0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-Baa  0  0   0  0 0   0
 Caa-Caa  0  0   0  0 0   0
attr(,"class")
[1] "matrix"
attr(,"call")
xtabs(formula = Count ~ ij + k, data = all.crossings)
```

An example of one of my 17 matrices:

```
          k
ij        Aa A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0 0   0  2  0   0
  A-B      0 0   0  0  1   0
  A-Ba     0 0   0  0  2   0
  A-Baa    0 0   1  0  0   0
  B-A      0 1   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0 0   0  2 13   8
  B-Ba     0 0   1  4  6   3
  B-Baa    0 0   2  0  1   1
  B-Caa    0 0   0  0  5   7
  Ba-A     1 0   1  0  0   0
  Ba-B     0 0   1  4  6   4
  Ba-Ba    0 0   3  4  0   1
  Ba-Baa   0 0   0  2  0   0
  Ba-Caa   0 0   0  0  0   3
  Baa-Aa   0 0   0  1  0   0
  Baa-B    0 0   0  4  2   1
  Baa-Ba   1 1   0  0  2   1
  Baa-Baa  0 0   6  2  0   0
  Baa-Caa  0 0   0  1  1   0
  Caa-B    0 1   0  2  3   4
  Caa-Ba   0 0   0  1  2   1
  Caa-Caa  0 0   0  1 10  17
attr(,"class")
[1] "matrix"
attr(,"call")
xtabs(formula = Count ~ ij + k, data = count.mat000102)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that for each matrices, you make all the rows the same, i.e. adding new rows and fill with 0. After that, sort the matrices by row names.

In that way, you can add up the matrices more easily, just by `Matrix1 + Matrix2 + Matrix3`.

As suggested by your edited answer, I created a new matrix with all `0`.

```
Matrix0

        Aa A Baa Ba B Caa
Aa-Aa    0 0   0  0 0   0
Aa-A     0 0   0  0 0   0
Aa-Baa   0 0   0  0 0   0
Aa-Ba    0 0   0  0 0   0
Aa-B     0 0   0  0 0   0
Aa-Caa   0 0   0  0 0   0
A-Aa     0 0   0  0 0   0
A-A      0 0   0  0 0   0
A-Baa    0 0   0  0 0   0
A-Ba     0 0   0  0 0   0
A-B      0 0   0  0 0   0
A-Caa    0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-Aa   0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-A    0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-Baa  0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-Ba   0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-B    0 0   0  0 0   0
Baa-Caa  0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-Aa    0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-A     0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-Baa   0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-Ba    0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-B     0 0   0  0 0   0
Ba-Caa   0 0   0  0 0   0
B-Aa     0 0   0  0 0   0
B-A      0 0   0  0 0   0
B-Baa    0 0   0  0 0   0
B-Ba     0 0   0  0 0   0
B-B      0 0   0  0 0   0
B-Caa    0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-Aa   0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-A    0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-Baa  0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-Ba   0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-B    0 0   0  0 0   0
Caa-Caa  0 0   0  0 0   0
```

For the matrix with incomplete number of rows, I have it as

```
Matrix1

        Aa A Baa Ba  B Caa
A-A      0 0   0  2  0   0
A-B      0 0   0  0  1   0
A-Ba     0 0   0  0  2   0
A-Baa    0 0   1  0  0   0
B-A      0 1   0  0  0   0
B-B      0 0   0  2 13   8
B-Ba     0 0   1  4  6   3
B-Baa    0 0   2  0  1   1
B-Caa    0 0   0  0  5   7
Ba-A     1 0   1  0  0   0
Ba-B     0 0   1  4  6   4
Ba-Ba    0 0   3  4  0   1
Ba-Baa   0 0   0  2  0   0
Ba-Caa   0 0   0  0  0   3
Baa-Aa   0 0   0  1  0   0
Baa-B    0 0   0  4  2   1
Baa-Ba   1 1   0  0  2   1
Baa-Baa  0 0   6  2  0   0
Baa-Caa  0 0   0  1  1   0
Caa-B    0 1   0  2  3   4
Caa-Ba   0 0   0  1  2   1
Caa-Caa  0 0   0  1 10  17
```

From here, what I can do is to bind the rows of Matrix1, with the rows from Matrix0 that do not already exist in Matrix1.

```
Matrix1 <- rbind(Matrix1, Matrix0[!row.names(Matrix0) %in% row.names(Matrix1), ])
```

Then, to make sure the addition is meaningful, I sorted the order of the rows,

```
Matrix1 <- Matrix1[row.names(Matrix0), ]
```

Repeat these two lines of codes for all your 17 matrices, then you should be able to add them up.

Comment: I've made these changes but I'm unable to add them together. I've updated my original question.

Comment: @gm007 It cannot work the way you mentioned in the question, I am afraid. Matrices of different dimensions cannot be summed. The idea is to make the 17 matrices all have same dimensions, row names and column names, then sum them up.

Comment: @gm007 I have updated my answer. Hope that will work for you.